# Con tool not working In ArcGIS Desktop 10.5?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.5, con, error-001143

I have a raster dataset [Flow Accumulation  Raster]. Which is located in gdb. I need to perform Con Tool operation with this raster dataset. The Con Tool operation runs successfully with this dataset in ArcGIS 10.1,10.2,10.3 and 10.4 but it does not work in 10.5.

To perform Con Tool these steps I followed in Python window of ArcGIS:
*FlowAccumulationRaster* is available in TOC.

```python
>>> import sys
>>> import arcpy
>>> from arcpy import env
>>> from arcpy.sa import *
>>> env.workspace = "C:\StreamCreationTes.gdb"
>>> env.scratchWorkspace = "C:\StreamCreationTes.gdb"
>>> spFactoryCode = int(32628)
>>> arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    u'CheckedOut'
>>> spRef = arcpy.SpatialReference()
>>> spRef.factoryCode = spFactoryCode
>>> spRef.create()
>>> arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem =  spRef
>>> outConditional = Con("FlowAccumulationRaster","FlowAccumulationRaster, 
    "", "VALUE > 10000")
```

I got this error message.

> error Message: Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in    File "c:\program files
> (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 263, in
> Con     where_clause)   File "c:\program files
> (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
> result = wrapper(*args, *kwargs)   File "c:\program files
> (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 257, in
> Wrapper     where_clause)   File "c:\program files
> (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line
> 510, in      return lambda args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
> ExecuteError: ERROR 001143: Background server threw an exception.

This is the Geoprocessing Options settings of my ArcGIS.
[image: Geoprocessing Options]

Can anyone help in this regard?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include a screenshot of the Con tool and the specific error you're getting?

Comment: have you tried running your tool in foreground ?

Comment: Please always provide code and any error messages as text rather than pictures.

Comment: Your first picture says "SteamCreationTes**t**.gdb" the second one says "St**r**eamCreationTes.gdb"

Comment: I'm just pointing it out so you can double check whether these are both valid pathnames for these geodatabases. And that both geodatabases contain the raster.

Comment: @RJJoling, __C:\StreamCreationTes.gdb__ is a valid pathname.The input raster is in different gdb and available in TOC.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the issue is due to the Background Geoprocessing.

You can disable background processing from the geoprocessing menu, **`Geoprocessing Options...`**

[image]

Then untick the enable box.

[image]

Run your code again.

Comment: I had tried but still did not work.

Comment: Do you get the same error?

Comment: hmm................................

Comment: When possible I avoid using fgdb for raster calculation. Try that, it might surprise you.